# Проблема с опубликованием обновления приложения в Play Console

Tags: android, update, обновление, google-play-console

Решил обновить приложение свое, внес изменения, изменил версию в Gradle, создал подписанный APK, пробую выложить не получается. Все нужные поля при обновлении заполнил (APK загрузил, система его приняла, название версии, что нового в версии). Но кнопка "Просмотреть" все равно недоступна. Страницу обновлял, кэш и cookie чистил. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в Гугле,глобальная :) там кажется они берут сутки на проверку того чего залили, до этого оно вроде не активное.. если мы одно и тоже явление имеем в виду. Ещё можно им в саппорт вопрос задать

Answer (score 0):

На проверку приложения и добавление в стор требуется время, по своему опыту могу сказать где то сутки. Но в поиске его и потом будет сложно найти

Comment: А у меня не добавление с нуля, а обновление, обычно на это тратилось 2-3 часа, а тут даже не получается отослать на рассмотрение. Кнопка "Просмотреть" на этапе "Подготовка версии" неактивна

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не выполнили какие-то новые условия Гугл.

Поищите по вкладкам в консоли. Например, не так давно там появлялось новое поле, необходимое для заполнения: 
**Настройка страницы приложения => Цены и распространение: `Для детей`**

Возможно еще какие-то поля у вас не заполнены (например, политика конфиденциальности для приложений, имеющих доступ к контактам и т.п.)

Comment: Абсолютно все заполнено! Проблема остается до сих пор

Answer (score 0):

1. Может быть, у вашего приложения нашли какие-нибудь нарушения... (читайте сообщения)
2. Но, **скорее всего, вы бросили предыдущее внедрение на стадии черновика**.
   Зайдите во вкладку **Выпуски** и там всё увидите... Либо продолжите работу с черновиком, либо удалите черновик (станет доступной желанная кнопка) и создайте новый выпуск.